# MongoDB , zsh: command not found: mongo

Tags: mongodb

I just installed MongoDB through homebrew and ran it as a macOS service, then I started the server with command:

brew services start mongodb-community@4.4

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@4.4` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4)

so it's running

but when I tried to run the mongo shell with command: mongo
it just showed zsh: command not found: mongo

Answer (score 1):

add the mongo location path to the zsh PATH variable:

```
echo export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@4.4/bin:$PATH >> ~/.zshrc
```

open new terminal and try starting again